# Short story about woman missionary on another planet, fighting a fellow missionary and getting pregnant?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I remember reading a short story in a collection last year about a woman who goes to space to teach aliens about Christianity.

She ended up fighting against a fellow missionary and his (tribe). She had to learn the alien tribe's language, and she got pregnant at the end.

I don't remember when it was published, sorry, and I thought I remembered a few other stories in it, but I found the book they were published in, and this story was not in there. Ugh.

Comment: Hi there. Can you maybe [edit] in when it would have been published? Also, any recollection of the collection's cover or the other stories it contained?

Comment: Did she have to learn the alien tribe's language? The missionary's? Both?

Comment: the aliens language @FuzzyBoots

Comment: I edited it in @Jenayah

Comment: If you found your answer, please post it as a self-answer below :)

Comment: Also, you don't need to add "edit" each time you make an edit. The system already takes care of that for you in the [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/211173/revisions). Just make the changes you need to and we can see them :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're thinking of L. Sprague de Camp's *[Galton Whistle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Galton_Whistle)*?

> Surveyor Adrian Frome, one of a three-member survey team working in the jungles of the planet Vishnu, is captured by the centaur-like Dzlieri natives after his supervisor is killed and the third member deserts. Taken to their base, he finds them taking orders from Sirat Mongkut, a Terran previously lost in the area, who is pretending to be a god and has ambitions of uniting the Dzlieri tribes under himself as emperor. He uses an ultrasonic whistle than only the Dzlieri can hear to bolster his authority. Another captive is Elena Millán, a female missionary who had also gone missing. Faced with the choice of joining his captor's cause or death, Frome pretends to enlist, while actually seeking an opportunity to thwart the madman's grandiose scheme and escape. When it arises, he kills Sirat and absconds with Elena, making for the peak that was the goal of the survey, from which he hopes to signal for aid. Successfully rescued, he puts in for a transfer to Ganesha, another world in the star system to escape Elena in turn; having formed a romantic liaison with her, he has since discovered she is an incurable fanatic.

Comment: The more I look into this, the worse match it seems, but I'll keep it up there for the combination of aliens and female missionaries.